# How do I use variables in Cloudflare Durable Objects

Tags: cloudflare-workers

I have been playing with the cloudflare chat demo https://github.com/cloudflare/workers-chat-demo in an attempt to better understand Durable Objects. I would like to use a secret value in my worker, I have the code working fine in a 'normal' worker but if I set up a secret and try to access it anywhere in my code (even before calling the Durable Object) it can't recognize the secret variable name. Is there something additional I need to configure to use the secret in a class based worker/one with a Durable Object registered?

Answer (score 2):

In module based Workers your bindings are passed in the `env` parameter, rather than being pushed into your global scope.

Example from the Chat demo, `env` passed into `fetch`: https://github.com/cloudflare/workers-chat-demo/blob/66f513acb23fd5acafbc2efba4385d1a1becd7fc/src/chat.mjs#L95

A binding on `env` being used: https://github.com/cloudflare/workers-chat-demo/blob/66f513acb23fd5acafbc2efba4385d1a1becd7fc/src/chat.mjs#L143

You should be able to access your secret binding in the same way.